# Hibernate RIGHT JOIN result not mapping correctly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a datasource and ds_restriction tables. I want to select all data sources regardless they have restricted or not in hibernate. Here is mapped classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="datasource")
public class DatasourceDom implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")    
private int id;

@Column(name = "alias")
private String alias;   

@Column(name = "url")
private String url;


@Entity
@Table(name = "ds_restriction")
public class DsRestrictionDom implements Serializable { 

@Id
@Column(name = "datasource_id")
private int datasourceId;

@Id
@Column(name = "principal")
private String principal;   

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "datasource_id")
@ElementCollection(targetClass = DatasourceDom.class)
private DatasourceDom datasource;
```

And here is my code to get datasources:

```
public List<DatasourceRestrictionDom> getDatasorcesRestictions() {
    Session session = getCurrentSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DsRestrictionDom.class);
    criteria.createCriteria("datasource","ds",JoinType.RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN);
    List<DatasourceRestrictionDom> dsList = criteria.list();        
    return dsList;
}
```

When I get result, the datasources which haven't restrictions returns null.
What is incorrect in mapping?

Comment: why do you need '@ElementCollection when you already marked datasource as '@ManyToOne ?

Comment: doesn't the join type should be left outer join?

Comment: No, it should be right outer join. I set show_sql=true and see the query. When I run the query it is working correctly, that's why I think that problem is in mapping.